# onDeviceReady() don´t fire in Crosswalk Cordova Project

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

The method onDeviceRead() don´t fire when I am running it in an Crosswalk-Cordova-Project.

I have tested the following versions of Crosswalk Cordova Android(ARM):

-11.40.277.7
-12.41.296.4
-13.41.313.0

I am using cordova 3.6.3

Here is my Code from the HTML-File:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />                         
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert("123");
        }            

    </script>

</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is the documentation from cordova: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you able to see 'Apache cordova. Device is Ready` on the Mobile screen? Try to comment the `app.initialize()` call and check if it alerts `123` on the screen. Also check if `cordova.js` is available in `your_project\platforms\android\assets\www` directory

Comment: Yes, i can see "Apache cordova. Device is Ready" on the mobile screen(Do you mean the content of the <div class="app"> - tag? ). I commented the app.initialize() call and nothing happend. Still can´t see the the alert. The cordova.js is available in the directory. I already replaced the cordova.js with a newer version of cordova. Nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If you can see `Apache cordova. Device is Ready` which means that the cordova api has been initialized. The `Apache cordova. Device is Ready` is set by the `app.initialize()` call which is located in the `index.js` file.

To make it simpler. just comment the `app.initialize()` call. Remove the onload attribute in the `body` tag and **replace** the following code in the **script** tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  // device APIs are available
  //
  function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("123");
  }            

</script>
```

You should see an alert on your screen.

Comment: still can´t see the alert :-/ Where exactly should i see "apache cordova. Device is Ready"

Comment: you said in your earlier comment that you can see "apache cordova. Device is Ready" in your mobile screen.? How did you get to that point in your program?

Comment: I meant that I can see the content of the HTML-File. In The HTML-File is mentioned <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>

Comment: If start the html-file in chrome i get a few failures. Here it is:                    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
index.html:122 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Comment: So the cordova.js and the index.js won´t execute when running the index.html in the windows chrome browser. Is that normal?

Comment: The cordova.js won't run in the windows chrome browser. Firstly because you might be using the `file://` protocol (i.e loading from the local file system) which is not allowed for security reasons. secondly the cordova.js file is dependent on java libraries that act as a bridget between the Webview JavaScript and the Native code. Can you try to recreate your project afresh and check whether the `deviceready` event is fired.? I am still not clear why you are not able to get the cordova stuff working.

Comment: can you gives us the steps as to how is your cordova project set up? what commands are  you running to setup/create your cordova project?

Comment: Isn´t it possible to debbug the app with this tutorial? http://gonzalo123.com/2014/08/04/debugging-android-cordovaphonegap-apps-with-chrome/

Comment: 1. create the HTML5-Cordova Project with Crosswalk: /path/to/crosswalk-cordova-android/bin/create HelloWorld com.example.helloworld HelloWorld
 
2. add the <script> tag from above with the onDeviceReady()-method                      3. go to the HelloWorld/cordova/ directory and start run.bat

Comment: Don´t know why but now it works! Thank you for your patience ;)

Comment: did you create a new project or your old project started working.

Comment: a new one. Even the css won´t execute in the old ones. Now i see the correct start screen of cordova. Very strange...

Comment: Sometimes Crosswalk creates a HTML-Project where the index.html or the css files have a different Encoding. That was the problem.